# How to read grouped records in XamDataGrid when grouping is set programatically in tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grouping, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm trying to write some test scenarios for the XamDataGrid. In these scenarios I'd like to set the grouping on a single Field. This code causes the grid to group as expected when I run the app and double-click the grid:

```
    Private Sub MyGrid_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles MyGrid.MouseDoubleClick
        Dim xamDataGrid As XamDataGrid = CType(sender, XamDataGrid)
        Dim field As Field = xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).Fields("A")
        Dim fieldSortDescription As New FieldSortDescription With {.Field = field, .Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending, .IsGroupBy = True}

        xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).SortedFields.Add(fieldSortDescription)
    End Sub
```

In tests, after running something very similar the Records and ViewableRecords collections do not reflect the grouping. `xamDataGrid.ViewableRecords(0)` is a DataRecord and not a GroupByRecord. Here's the code from the test:

```
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test()
        Dim xamDataGrid As New XamDataGrid

        xamDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.DefaultView
        xamDataGrid.BeginInit()
        xamDataGrid.EndInit()

        Dim field As Field = xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).Fields("A")
        Dim fieldSortDescription As New FieldSortDescription With {.Field = field, .Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending, .IsGroupBy = True}
        xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).SortedFields.Add(fieldSortDescription)

        ' exception thrown here because xamDataGrid.ViewableRecords(0) is a DataRecord
        Dim groupByRecord As GroupByRecord = CType(xamDataGrid.ViewableRecords(0), GroupByRecord)
        ' ...
    End Sub
```

How can the grid be refreshed or otherwise forced to reflect the grouping set by the code?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite accidentally I discovered that the Records and ViewableRecords collections are refreshed in tests by using the Dispatcher:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test()
    Dim xamDataGrid As New XamDataGrid

    xamDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.DefaultView
    xamDataGrid.BeginInit()
    xamDataGrid.EndInit()

    Dim field As Field = xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).Fields("A")
    Dim fieldSortDescription As New FieldSortDescription With {.Field = field, .Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending, .IsGroupBy = True}
    xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts(0).SortedFields.Add(fieldSortDescription)

    ' this line refreshes record collections
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                   End Sub), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle)

    ' exception not thrown!
    Dim groupByRecord As GroupByRecord = CType(xamDataGrid.ViewableRecords(0), GroupByRecord)
    ' ...
End Sub
```